# Changing diaspora pod name in heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, diaspora

I had a working diaspora pod on herokru. But I want to change my pod name to something else but it seems to much complicated. As directed on https://wiki.diasporafoundation.org/Installation/Heroku I tried following these steps:

```
## You can set and/or override all these settings through environment variables
## with the following conversion rules:
## - Strip the top level namespace (configuration, production, etc.)
## - Build the path to the setting, for example environment.s3.enable
## - Replace the dots with underscores: environment_s3_enable
## - Convert to upper case: ENVIRONMENT_S3_ENABLE
## - Specify lists/arrays as comma-separated values
```

but did not understand what to do. Can anybody please explain me what the exact way of changing the pod name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's copy paste my email reply *again*.

> ```
> ## You can set and/or override all these settings through environment variables
> ## with the following conversion rules:
> ## - Strip the top level namespace (configuration, production, etc.)
> ## - Build the path to the setting, for example environment.s3.enable
> ## - Replace the dots with underscores: environment_s3_enable
> ## - Convert to upper case: ENVIRONMENT_S3_ENABLE
> ## - Specify lists/arrays as comma-separated values
> ##
> ## - For example, on Heroku:
> ##   heroku config:set SERVICES_FACEBOOK_APP_ID=yourappid SERVICES_FACEBOOK_SECRET=yourappsecret
> ```
>
> ```

Let's copy paste *the example explaining how to configure your pod* and replace the setting.

```
## You can set and/or override all these settings through environment variables
## with the following conversion rules:
## - Strip the top level namespace (configuration, production, etc.)
## - Build the path to the setting, for example settings.pod_name
## - Replace the dots with underscores: settings_pod_name
## - Convert to upper case: SETTINGS_POD_NAME
## - Specify lists/arrays as comma-separated values
##
## - For example, on Heroku:
##   heroku config:set SETTINGS_POD_NAME="My cool diaspora"
```